# Flask SQLAlchemy KeyError 'False' in create_engine

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-mysql

I have a flask app that connects with mysql using sqlalchemy. A strange error happens on DB query.

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1008, in **call**
> return self.registry[key]
> KeyError: <greenlet.greenlet object at 0x7f22a0936a90 (otid=0x7f22a08ef100) current active started main>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/server/users/routes.py", line
> 28, in register_new_user
> if form.validate_on_submit():   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_wtf/form.py",
> line 100, in validate_on_submit
> return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/form.py",
> line 318, in validate
> return super(Form, self).validate(extra)   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/form.py",
> line 150, in validate
> if not field.validate(self, extra):   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py",
> line 226, in validate
> stop_validation = self._run_validation_chain(form, chain)   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py",
> line 246, in _run_validation_chain
> validator(form, self)   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/server/users/forms.py", line
> 43, in validate_email
> user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
> line 552, in **get**
> return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py",
> line 47, in **call**
> sess = self.registry()   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/*collections.py", line 1010, in **call**
> return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
> line 4171, in **call**
> return self.class*(**local_kw)   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
> line 176, in **init**
> bind = options.pop('bind', None) or db.engine   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
> line 998, in engine
> return self.get_engine()   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
> line 1017, in get_engine
> return connector.get_engine()   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
> line 594, in get_engine
> self._engine = rv = self._sa.create_engine(sa_url, options)   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
> line 1027, in create_engine
> return sqlalchemy.create_engine(sa_url, **engine_opts)   File "", line 2, in create_engine   File
> "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 298, in warned
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py",
> line 661, in create_engine
> engine = engineclass(pool, dialect, u, **engine_args)   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 2758, in **init**
> self.echo = echo   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/log.py",
> line 225, in **set**
> instance_logger(instance, echoflag=value)   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/log.py",
> line 202, in instance_logger
> logger = InstanceLogger(echoflag, name)   File "/home/Desktop/work/nesting-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/log.py",
> line 103, in **init**
> if self._echo_map[echo] <= logging.INFO and not self.logger.handlers: KeyError: 'False' `

Here is the config.py

```
from os import environ, path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
load_dotenv(path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))


class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname'
    # SQLALCHEMY_ECHO: When set to 'True', Flask-SQLAlchemy will log all database
    # activity to Python's stderr for debugging purposes.
    SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_ECHO')
    #  To suppress the warning "this option takes a lot of system resources" set
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS')
```

Here is the **init.py**

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'
mail = Mail()
csrf = CSRFProtect()


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    flask_app = Flask(__name__)
    flask_app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(flask_app)
    bcrypt.init_app(flask_app)
    login_manager.init_app(flask_app)
    mail.init_app(flask_app)
    csrf.init_app(flask_app)
```

I have tried with different connection strings:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pass@localhost:3306/dbname

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pass@localhost/dbname

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pass@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The `echo` flag for SQLAlchemy's `create_engine` function accepts a limited set of values: `None`, `False`, `True`, `"debug"` ([source](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/7f8bf038b753d3f250e0e974102c16037d1aea5d/lib/sqlalchemy/log.py#L90)).

The traceback shows that the *string* `"False"` is being passed: `KeyError: 'False'`.  In fact, the error can be reproduced by passing any string (except "debug") as the value of `create_engine`'s `echo` flag:

```
create_engine('sqlite://', echo='banana')
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
KeyError: 'banana'
```

At a guess, the problem is that

```
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_ECHO')
```

does not consider that environment variables are always strings.  Something like this might be better:

```
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_ECHO') in ('1', 'True')
```

as it will result in a boolean value being assigned.